# json4s throws NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/Timestamp

Tags: scala, json4s

When following the [json4s instructions on Serialization](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/master/README.md#serialization) I keep getting the followinng error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/Timestamp
> at org.json4s.reflect.Reflector$.(Reflector.scala:22)
> at org.json4s.reflect.Reflector$.(Reflector.scala)
> at org.json4s.Extraction$.internalDecomposeWithBuilder(Extraction.scala:160)
> at org.json4s.Extraction$.decomposeWithBuilder(Extraction.scala:65)
> at org.json4s.native.Serialization$.write(Serialization.scala:43)
> at org.json4s.native.Serialization$.write(Serialization.scala:37)
> ... 34 elided
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.Timestamp
> at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:436)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
> ... 40 more

My case class does not have any `java.sql.Timemstamp` values.

**What is needed to setup scala 2.12, and openjdk 12, with json4s properly?**

I have setup my sbt in compliance with the instructions and I am able to `import java.sql.Timestamp` in my project.

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Comment: Try with JDK 8.

Comment: @IvanKurchenko Thank you for the suggestion!  However, I don't have the option to change jdk versions.